# 24-hour time drop-down

Tags: html

Having a mental block due to caffeine depravation...

If I add two drop-downs to select time in 24-hour (military) format do I put 24 options for hours or 23? In minutes we won't put 60, but rather 59... But in this case, how does one set a midnight?

```
<select name="hour">
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    ...
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not really a programming issue; it is a need for clarification about military time. As such it is technically not an appropriate Stack Overflow question. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way is prepending a `00`.

`00:15` for `12:15am`

Answer (score 3):

start minutes and hours from 00, so midnight will be **00:00**

Answer (score 1):

You should start at `00`. That's midnight. End at `23`.

Answer (score 0):

for 24-hour system hour drop-down values should be **00-23**, minutes and seconds **00-59**.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your phone clock to 24 hrs mode. Midnight is 00:00.